# Built in method to return SQL column count

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I'm curious is there any built in method that can count the number of columns in an sql query based on the DataReader result. (I'm not talking about `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X"`)

For example this can be carried out in Java by using the `ResultSetMetaData` class that has a `.getColumnCount()` method. This is useful when formatting and putting the results of a query in a list without actually knowing how many columns there are.

I'd like know if such method exists in C# as well.

Comment: dataReader.GetSchemaTable().Columns.Count ?

Comment: @JackNewcombe: Thank you, Perfect answer Jack, I'd accept this as an answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it on the SchemaTable for the data reader:

```
dataReader.GetSchemaTable().Columns.Count
```